# Extract data from list of dictionaries in R

Tags: json, r, parsing, dictionary

I have a dataframe with a column that contains a list of dictionaries as a character string.

Small reproducible example:

```
ids <- c('[{"type":"A","value":"666"},{"type":"M","value":"029"},{"type":"A","value":"ABC"},{"type":"E","value":"5"},{"type":"E34","value":"456"}]',
         '[{"type":"G","value":"334"},{"type":"A","value":"ZG5"},{"type":"E","value":"098"}]')

dt <- as.data.frame(ids)
dt
```

What I would like to do is to create a new column in dt called `dt$A` which contains the first value of `"type":"A"` for each corresponding row.

There is always at least one `"type":"A"` for each row.

In the example above I would like to get:

```
> dt$A
[1] "666" "ZG5"
```

So far I'have tried using `rjson` library but I wasn't able to extract the values that I want and I haven't figured out how to apply that to every row of dt.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `regex`.  Remove the double quotes using `gsub` and extract the word that follows tha `A,value:` with `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
dt$A <- str_extract(gsub('"', "", dt$ids), "(?<=A,value:)\\w+")
dt$A
#[1] "666" "ZG5"
```

Comment: As a regex newbie, this is how I feel whenever somebody on SO effortlessly solves a problem with one line of code...
https://xkcd.com/208/

Comment: @AndrewBrēza  I also felt the same way some years back when somebody did the regex in Perl.  Then, I picked up in Perl using regex.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

@AndrewBrēza LOL